# Не работает ни внешняя, ни встроенная звуковая карта компьютера

Tags: железо

Очень много лет назад перестали работать разъемы передней панели. Этот факт не смогли изменить ни переустановка драйверов (даже после удаления предыдущих), ни переустановка ОС. Внутри визуально все провода целые, все перемычки на разъеме присутствуют.

Решили проблему использованием только задних разъемов. Полгода назад отказали и они. Решили проблему покупкой внешней USB звуковой карты (3D sound). Помогло.

Но недавно перестала работать и она! Причем на другом компьютере она работает, стало быть проблема в самом компе. Опять же никакие смены драйверов, ОС, чистка разъемов не помогли.

Сама встроенная звуковая карта обнаруживается. 
При включении наушников в переднее гнездо: в диспетчере Realtek не происходит никаких событий, в наушниках шум.

При включении в заднее гнездо в диспетчере спрашивает "Какое устройство вы хотите подключить?". При варианте "Наушники" в наушниках появляется только шум. При варианте "Выход на передние динамики" в наушниках тишина.

При включении через внешнюю звуковую никакой реакции системы.
В BIOS передняя панель включена, выбран кодек HD Audio (как и в диспетчере Realtek). При смене кодека на AC97 (в Realtek и BIOS) все то же самое. Переменные в реестре написаны правильно. K-Lite Codec Pack установлен. Реакция на наушники и динамики одинаковая.

Материнская плата ASUSTeK Computer INC. M5A78L-M LX3 (AM3R2).
Есть у кого нибудь какие нибудь идеи, почему это может происходить?

Comment: Данный вопрос не относится к [тематике сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Если раньше все работало, а потом перестало, то попробуйте переставить винду. Только с нуля.